# failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v0.6.1+6.28.2`

Tags: substrate-node-template, build

When I use the command `cargo build --release` to build substrate-node-template on version `polkadot-v0.9.26`, the following  error is emitted:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v0.6.1+6.28.2`
```

```
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `.../substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-60f437c04bdca76d/build-script-build` (exit status: 127)
  --- stderr
  Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 678: _dl_open: Assertion `_dl_debug_initialize (0, args.nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!
```

> rust version: rustc 1.62.1 (e092d0b6b 2022-07-16)    OS version:

> CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

Comment: Are you running this in tty terminal or are you piping the output?

Comment: @SudipGhimire yes, I tried in IntelliJ IDEA 's terminal and Xshell terminate

Comment: Maybe you can once try to run it in dedicated terminal app like gnome-terminal or something. It looks like some unexpected behaviour to io

Comment: I recommend you make sure you covered all steps here: https://docs.substrate.io/main-docs/install/linux

Comment: thank you all, I have resolved this by compiling and installing GCC, LLVM from source.

Comment: @yoyo Could you share some links what you have made exactly?

Comment: use this command this works for me for exact same issue `brew install openssl cmake llvm`